# Do src and dst of push will be the same?

Tags: git, git-push

We know if a `push` command uses a `refspec` which has `+` sign, it will overwrite `dst` completely (`non-fast-forward` update) so `dst` and `src` will be the same. But is that true if a `fast-forward` update occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is that true if a fast-forward update occurs?

Yes, considering a fast-forward simply moves the remote head dst to src (because src only adds new commits)

```
--r--r--r--o--o--o (src)
        |
   (origin/dst)

git push +src:dst

--r--r--r--o--o--o (src)
                 |
            (origin/dst)
```

From [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> By having the optional leading `+`, you can tell Git to update the `<dst>` ref even if it is not allowed by default (e.g., it is not a fast-forward.)

That means: if the push is a fast-forward one, the '`+`' has no effect.